# Converting decimal numbers to binary in python using a 2D list

Tags: python, list, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a code in python which will take a number as input which will define how much bits I want to represent each number in, and then print out all the numbers that that number of bits can represent in binary which will be integer value in a list. For example:

> Input :

```
Enter the number of bits : 3
```

> Output :

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

Comment: So this just writes all combinations of a binary number that has the amount of digits equal to the user input? This has several duplicates, duplicates you shouldve been able to find if you did research. `lst = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
num_bits = input("How many bits?")
bits_list = [ list(map(int, str('{0:0'+num_bits+'b}').format(i))) for i in range(2**int(num_bits))]
print(bits_list)
```

Comment: So nice of you! But the list elements should be integer value, not string :(

Comment: @MD.TanvirSarwar I just fixed it, it now has the list elements as integers. Try it again

Comment: Very complicated approach, also why would you just give him the code without OP doing bare minimum.... Also duplicate question.